# How are callback functions' parameters dependent on ordering?

Tags: javascript, parameters, callback, functional-programming

Let's say I have an event I'm waiting for in Javascript, where we'll have something like this:

```
fileSystem.readFile('done', function(err, data){
    //do something with the file
});
```

In this situation, the parameters err and data are arbitrarily named and ordered, so they could have been in another order

```
function(data, err) {/*do something*/ }
```

How does data get passed the data and err get passed any errors?

I notice this pattern to be pervasive everywhere through out javascript callbacks, and it is largely a mystery to me how function parameters are passed in a predictable order without following some convention I must not be aware of.

How does this work?

Comment: When event happens this callback function (stored somewhere as a reference) gets invoked with something like `callback(errorObject, dataObject)`.

Comment: what you describe seems impossible  if I did `function(x,y){...` it can't know which to put data and error into.

Comment: The person that wrote it designed it that way.

Comment: I guess the function that executes the callback can inspect the source of the callback and swap the paramters based on their names.

Comment: Do you realize you can name data and err anything you want?  `function(funky,chicken){` Do you realize when you swap the variable names, the content is not changed? err would contain data and data would contain err.

Comment: @epascarello yes I understand that, but I am asking what sets the conventions that err comes first followed by data.

Comment: @AdamBronfin There are no "conventions", other than that employed by a *particular* framework or library. It may be beneficial to follow the patterns found in common library, but such is outside the scope of JavaScript as a language. If that is the question, voting to close as opinion-based. (*Code that uses the library/function/callback wrong will get incorrect data in the parameters* or otherwise fail to work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that when you call

```
fileSystem.readFile('done', function(err, data){
    //do something with the file
});
```

the function you pass as the second parameter will be saved for later use (when the file is finished reading). It will then call the function you passed for you, with a possible error value as the first parameter, and the file contents as the second parameter.

```
readFile = function(event, callback) {
   var error = null;
   var fileContents = /* read file implementation. Maybe error will be assigned some value here */;

   callback(error, fileContents);
}
```

Of course, this is just some pseudo-code to illustrate my point.

Now, you can name your parameters in your function `function(err, data)` whatever you want, because they are in the scope you defined. Even if you swap their names `function(data, err)`, they will still contain the error and file content values respectively.